# Viewing photos from server

Tags: macos, photography

I have just taken the plunge and moved from a windows laptop, to a Mac Book Pro

I am a very keen amateur photographer and that was a driving force behind the Apple device (Retina Display)

My question is simple, I have photos stored on my server, how can I view them easily?

I have managed to share the drive so I can view one at a time. But I want to be able to just press Left/Right to scroll through them, and switch between "Zoom it fit" and "Actual size" much like you can on a doze machine

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select a photo in Finder and tap the spacebar for Quicklook. Press left and right arrow to move to next picture.

When you get to the rightmost image, pressing the right arrow will not take you to the next image - it doesn't *"wrap"*. So before you start viewing, change to "List View".

Comment: cheers dude! I'm sure ill spend the next few weeks learning new shortcuts etc